# Bot will not log an automod event if user has blocked the bot

Tags: python, discord.py

If someone says a bad word that triggers the automod, the bot will delete the message, DM the user, and log it in a log channel.

The problem is if someone blocks the bot and says a bad word, the bot can't DM the user which doesn't allow the bot to log the event in a log channel.

I tried multiple ways to fix this by adding `if` and `else` and `except` but those do not help. Below is the current code that I have already, so how can I make the bot still log the event if the offender has blocked the bot?

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
 
  curseWord = ['bad words here']
  msg_content = message.content.lower()  

  if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
    if message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
      return
    if message.author.id == 330988962162147329: #johnny
      return
    if message.author.id == 467715040087244800: #me
      return
    if message.author.id == 261578097978114050: #devvy
      return
    if message.author.id == 835307493558321172: #examplebot
      return

    await message.delete()
    embed=discord.Embed(title="No No Word", description=f"{message.author.mention}, Hey! Those words arent allowed here!", color=0x00FFFF)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    author = message.author
    pfp = author.avatar_url
    embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}", icon_url=pfp)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    dmembed=discord.Embed(title="AutoMod", description="You were caught saying a bad word!", color=0x00FFFF)
    dmembed.add_field(name="**Message:**", value=f"{msg_content}", inline=False)
    pfp = author.avatar_url
    dmembed.add_field(name="**Server:**", value=f"{message.guild.name}", inline=False)
    dmembed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}", icon_url=pfp)
    dmembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    with open('logchannel.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
      log_channel = json.load(fp)

    try:
      await message.author.send(embed=dmembed)
      if log_channel:
        log_channel = message.guild.get_channel(log_channel[str(message.guild.id)])
        logembed=discord.Embed(title="Bot Log", description="Bad Word Said", color=0x00FFFF)
        logembed.add_field(name="**Message:**", value=f"{msg_content}", inline=False)
        logembed.add_field(name="**Member:**", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
        author = message.author
        pfp = author.avatar_url
        logembed.set_author(name=f"{author}", icon_url=pfp)
        logembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await log_channel.send(embed=logembed)
      else:
        await log_channel.send(embed=logembed)
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
      await log_channel.send(embed=logembed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try/except

When you have a `try`/`except` in your code, Python will try to execute the code, and if there is and error he will execute the code in the `except` section. So a code in the `try` section may be not executed.

#### What in your code needs a `try`/`except` ?

In your code, the things which could raise an error are :

```
await message.author.send(embed=dmembed) #DM closed
log_channel = ...(log_channel[str(message.guild.id)]) #key error
await log_channel.send(embed=logembed) #NoneType has no attribute send (if the channel doesn't exist)
```

Which means that if there is an error on the first possibility, all the following code in the `try` will not be executed.

#### Solution

I advise you to have two `try`/`except`, the first for the DM, and the second for the log.
You code with my solution is now :

```
    try:
      await message.author.send(embed=dmembed)
    except:
        pass #ignore error if DM are closed
    try:
      if log_channel:
        log_channel = message.guild.get_channel(log_channel[str(message.guild.id)])
        logembed=discord.Embed(title="Bot Log", description="Bad Word Said", color=0x00FFFF)
        logembed.add_field(name="**Message:**", value=f"{msg_content}", inline=False)
        logembed.add_field(name="**Member:**", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
        author = message.author
        pfp = author.avatar_url
        logembed.set_author(name=f"{author}", icon_url=pfp)
        logembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await log_channel.send(embed=logembed)
      else: #You can remove that, because if `log_channel` is not, you can't send an embed
        await log_channel.send(embed=logembed) #So you can also remove that
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
      await log_channel.send(embed=logembed) #Same here, if the above code raises an error, this code can be executed without raising another error.
      pass
```